# Need to parse XML file tag 'Asset Id' & associated child tags using a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, xml

I have the following XML that I'd like to parse/select the 'Asset Id' from using some method from the shell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:EcomAssetMetadataTransaction xmlns:ns0="http://www.DDDDD.com/IntegrationObjects/EcomAssetMetadata/1.0.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.DDDDD.com/ICC/Types/MetaData/1.0">
<TransactionMetaData>
<ns2:SourceSystemName>FFFF</ns2:SourceSystemName>
<ns2:TransactionType>EcomAssetMetadata</ns2:TransactionType>
<ns2:UniqueTransactionID>3c1bffed-a914-457d-9e20-f07efb09d0ec</ns2:UniqueTransactionID>
<ns2:TransactionDateTime>2017-09-11T15:46:42.134+02:00</ns2:TransactionDateTime>
</TransactionMetaData>
<Payload>
<EcomAssetMetadatas>
<EcomAssetMetadata>
<Data>
<AssetId>229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b</AssetId>
<AssetType>StillMediaComponents/Lookbook</AssetType>
<Version>1</Version>
<FileLocation>LiquidPixels</FileLocation>
<FilePath>22/9a/229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b.jpg</FilePath>
<Brand>DDDDD</Brand>
<AllowedForUse>true</AllowedForUse>
<MainArticles>
<Article>
<ProductId>0515769</ProductId>
<ArticleId>003</ArticleId>
</Article>
</MainArticles>
<SubordinateArticles>
<Article>
<ProductId>0544951</ProductId>
<ArticleId>001</ArticleId>
</Article>
</SubordinateArticles>
<Angle>
<Facing>1</Facing>
<Identifier>C</Identifier>
<Packaging>0</Packaging>
<Number>1</Number>
</Angle>
<IsMultiPack>false</IsMultiPack>
</Data>
</EcomAssetMetadata>
</EcomAssetMetadatas>
</Payload>
</ns0:EcomAssetMetadataTransaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** using awk

```
awk -F '[<>]' '/AssetId/ {a=$3;next} /AllowedForUse/ {print FILENAME":"a":"$3}' *.xml
```

output:

```
test1.xml:229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b:true
test.xml:229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b:true
```

- search the pattern `AssetId` and saves the 3rd field in `a`
- then search for the pattern `AllowedForUse` and print 3rd field along with filename and `a`

**option 2:** using xmlstarlet

```
for i in `ls -f *.xml`
do
        ID=`xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /ns0:EcomAssetMetadataTransaction/Payload/EcomAssetMetadatas/EcomAssetMetadata/Data/AssetId -v . -n  $i`
        STATUS=`xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m /ns0:EcomAssetMetadataTransaction/Payload/EcomAssetMetadatas/EcomAssetMetadata/Data/AllowedForUse -v . -n $i`
        echo -e "$i,$ID,$STATUS"
done
```

Comment: Hi Siva thanks for quick reply but first solution is not retrieving anything.. the command just executes and doest get anything 
also along side asset id the ALLOWED TO USE FLAG should also be pulled and both of these tags are child tags of Data

Comment: option 2 doesnt seem to be working either as i need to execute installation of xmlstarlet ..is there any other way which can avoid the installation

Comment: @user305470 which Linux distro are you using?

Comment: i am using GNU/Linux on a EC2 instance

Comment: @user305470 you can use any framework that provides an XML parser - for example, python's [minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

Comment: @SivaPrasath would prefer to use a shell so that i can schedule this on a daily basis and receive an output back

Comment: do not parse `ls` (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- `for i in *.xml` is correct

Comment: xmlstarlet can output multiple values: `read -r id status < <(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m //Data -v ./AssetId -o " " -v ./AllowedForUse file.xml)`

Comment: @glennjackman i dont have xmlstarlet on my linux instance, hence requesting a plain shell script .. its a AWS EC2  linux instance and i am not sure how to install xmlstarlet there ..

Comment: Try `sudo apt install xmlstarlet` -- you can't reliably parse XML with regular expressions

Comment: @glennjackman the above approach doesnt seem to work with EC2 as it uses yum i tried that as well but no luck ! it says - No package xmlstarlet available..

Comment: Then you should use Python or some other language that comes bundled with an XML processing library. Or if you like the look of xmlstarlet, go get the source and build it.

Comment: @glennjackman are we then saying that there are no means to put this onto a sh script? unfortunately i have limited options available .. can it be achieved via a sh script?

Comment: I don't understand why so many people are so resistant to this: use an XML parser to parse XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of XML parsing using a programming language (ruby) that comes with an XML parser:

```
ruby -e '
  require "rexml/document"
  file = File.new ARGV.shift
  doc = REXML::Document.new file
  REXML::XPath.each(doc, "//Data") do |elem|
    puts elem.elements["AssetId"].text
    puts elem.elements["AllowedForUse"].text
  end
' file.xml
```

Comment: i was able to write the shell script but unfortunately its not looping to scan every single xml file in the directory .. help!
!/bin/sh
DIR=`/home/ec2-user/`
   for FILE in ls "$DIR"*.xml
   do
  AssetId=$(sed -ne '/AssetId/{s/.*<AssetId>\(.*\)<\/AssetId>.*/\1/p;q;}' $FILE )
  AllowedForUse=$(sed -ne '/AllowedForUse/{s/.*<AllowedForUse>\(.*\)<\/AllowedForUse>.*/\1/p;q;}' $FILE )
  echo $AssetId::::::::::::$AllowedForUse
 done
OUTPUT IS ONLY ONE XML CONTENT - it's not looping 
229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b::true
229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b::true

Comment: paste your code into http://www.shellcheck.net to find errors and solutions

Answer (score 0):

Using `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//AssetId' -nl file.xml
229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b
```

or, with [`xq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/),

```
$ xq -r '.. | .AssetId? // empty' file.xml
229a916d778148de71522e6870822b5f841c794b
```

This would extract the value of any `AssetId` node anywhere in the document.  The exact path to the node in the document is `/ns0:EcomAssetMetadataTransaction/Payload/EcomAssetMetadatas/EcomAssetMetadata/Data/AssetId`, but it's unclear whether this is needed (not if there only will ever be one `AssetId` node).